# Updating a list item in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

I want to update a list item in a dictionary of items. I am able to do it by creating a new dictionary and over writing the original dictionary. I do not want to create a new dictionary each time as I have multiple such dictionaries to update. Is there a better way to do it? Also, output of my command is not the same list every-time, so different items needed to be added to file list.

Appreciate your help on this.

My working code:

### tmp.yml

```yaml
- name: Loop over specific keys in a dictionary
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    java_keystore_cred_list:
      - { application_name: keystore_certs,
          certs_dir_path: '/etc/keystore',
          command: "ls -1 ./*.yml",
          filelist: []
        }
      - { application_name: app_certs,
          certs_dir_path: '/etc/keystore/app_certs',
          command: "ls -1 ./*.yml",
          filelist: []
        }
    new_cred_list: []

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: java_keystore_cred_list

    - name: Update credential 
      include_tasks: tmp2.yml
      loop: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list }}"

    - name: Update java_keystore_cred_list
      set_fact:
        java_keystore_cred_list: "{{ new_cred_list }}"

    - debug:
        var: java_keystore_cred_list
```

### tmp2.yml

```yaml
- name: Get filelist
  shell: "{{ item.command }}"
  register: result

- name: Update filelist in item
  set_fact:
    tmp_item: "{{ item | combine({'filelist': result.stdout_lines | from_yaml}) }}"

- name: Update new_cred_list
  set_fact:
    new_cred_list: "{{ (new_cred_list | default([])) + [ tmp_item ] }}"
```

### output

```
ansible-playbook tmp.yml                                                                                           ✔  ansible2_13 
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Loop over specific keys in a dictionary] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  java_keystore_cred_list:
  - application_name: keystore_certs
    certs_dir_path: /etc/keystore
    command: ls -1 ./*.yml
    filelist: []
  - application_name: app_certs
    certs_dir_path: /etc/keystore/app_certs
    command: ls -1 ./*.yml
    filelist: []

TASK [Update credential map] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Users/umesh/AnsibleDemo/stackoverflow/myquestions/tmp2.yml for localhost => (item={'application_name': 'keystore_certs', 'certs_dir_path': '/etc/keystore', 'command': 'ls -1 ./*.yml', 'filelist': []})
included: /Users/umesh/AnsibleDemo/stackoverflow/myquestions/tmp2.yml for localhost => (item={'application_name': 'app_certs', 'certs_dir_path': '/etc/keystore/app_certs', 'command': 'ls -1 ./*.yml', 'filelist': []})

TASK [Get filelist] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Update filelist in item] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Update new_cred_list] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get filelist] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Update filelist in item] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Update new_cred_list] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Update java_keystore_cred_list] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  java_keystore_cred_list:
  - application_name: keystore_certs
    certs_dir_path: /etc/keystore
    command: ls -1 ./*.yml
    filelist:
    - ./tmp.yml
    - ./tmp2.yml
  - application_name: app_certs
    certs_dir_path: /etc/keystore/app_certs
    command: ls -1 ./*.yml
    filelist:
    - ./tmp.yml
    - ./tmp2.yml

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=11   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: `dictionary[key][index] = new_value` will update an element of a list in a dictionary. `dictionary[key].append(new_value)` will add to the list in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/etc/keystore
/tmp/etc/keystore
├── app_certs
│   ├── foo
│   ├── tmp1.yml
│   └── tmp2.yml
├── bar
├── tmp3.yml
└── tmp4.yml

1 directory, 6 files
```

and the list

```yaml
  java_keystore_cred_list:
    - application_name: keystore_certs
      certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore
      command: "ls -1 *.yml"
      filelist: []
    - application_name: app_certs
      certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore/app_certs
      command: "ls -1 *.yml"
      filelist: []
```

List the directories in the loop

```yaml
    - shell: "cd {{ item.certs_dir_path }}; {{ item.command }}"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list }}"
```

Declare the dictionary *name_filelist* by using the registered variable *result*

```yaml
  name_filelist: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query(name_filelist_query)) }}"
  name_filelist_query: '[].[item.application_name, stdout_lines]'
```

give

```yaml
  name_filelist:
    app_certs:
    - tmp1.yml
    - tmp2.yml
    keystore_certs:
    - tmp3.yml
    - tmp4.yml
```

Update credentials. Convert this dictionary to a list by *dict2items*, *zip* the lists, and *combine* the items

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        java_keystore_cred_list: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list|
                                     zip(name_filelist|
                                         dict2items(key_name='application_name',
                                                    value_name='filelist'))|
                                     map('combine') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  java_keystore_cred_list:
  - application_name: keystore_certs
    certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore
    command: ls -1 *.yml
    filelist:
    - tmp3.yml
    - tmp4.yml
  - application_name: app_certs
    certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore/app_certs
    command: ls *.yml
    filelist:
    - tmp1.yml
    - tmp2.yml
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    java_keystore_cred_list:
      - application_name: keystore_certs
        certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore
        command: "ls -1 *.yml"
        filelist: []
      - application_name: app_certs
        certs_dir_path: /tmp/etc/keystore/app_certs
        command: "ls -1 *.yml"
        filelist: []

    name_filelist: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query(name_filelist_query)) }}"
    name_filelist_query: '[].[item.application_name, stdout_lines]'
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: java_keystore_cred_list
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - name: List credentials
      shell: "cd {{ item.certs_dir_path }}; {{ item.command }}"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list }}"
    - debug:
        var: name_filelist
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - name: Update credentials
      set_fact:
        java_keystore_cred_list: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list|
                                     zip(name_filelist|
                                         dict2items(key_name='application_name',
                                                    value_name='filelist'))|
                                     map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: java_keystore_cred_list
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to create a new dictionary each time as I have multiple such dictionaries to update

You basically don't have any other choice as this is how Ansible works

> Is there a better way to do it?

Your above example is quite verbose and could be reduced to something more efficient like:

```yaml
- name: Update list of dict with results from commands
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    java_keystore_cred_list:
      - { application_name: keystore_certs,
          certs_dir_path: '/etc/keystore',
          command: "ls -1 ./*.yml",
        }
      - { application_name: app_certs,
          certs_dir_path: '/etc/keystore/app_certs',
          command: "ls -1 ./*.yml",
        }

  tasks:
    - name: Get results from commands
      shell: "{{ item.command }}"
      loop: "{{ java_keystore_cred_list }}"
      register: command_output

    - name: Create our result dict
      set_fact:
        new_cred_list: >-
          {{
             new_cred_list | d([])
             +
             [item.item | combine({'filelist': item.stdout_lines})]
          }}
      loop: "{{ command_output.results }}"

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: new_cred_list
```